# Rails 2.1 content_tag in Helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2, actionviewhelper

Does anyone know how to include `content_tag` in helpers? I tried including `ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper`.

Comment: This may help .. http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag

Comment: The `content_tag` method should be available in your `ApplicationHelper` "out of the box" - are you getting some error when you try to call it in your `ApplicationHelper`?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def something(place, url)
    content_tag :li do
      link_to(place, url)
    end
  end
 end
```

Let me know if that works or if you still have problems.

Mike Riley

Comment: Ok! I figured it out. The content_tag method works when the helper name matches the controller exactly. Otherwise, it doesn't. Don't ask me why we have helpers that aren't matched to controllers. I did not write them.